# Anonymous function / Closure issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, anonymous-function

I want to create a class `Objective` with an implemented call-function. The clue is, when initializing the Objective class a variable called `function` is handed over which can be either a mathematical function string or a python function itself. The `__init__` has now the task to find out what the input is (string or callable function) and declare the variable/function `func`, which is return of the `__call__`.
The code right now looks a little like this:

```
class Objective():
    def __init__(self, function):
        if isinstance(function, str):
            def func(self,x):
               return eval(function,x)

        elif callable(function):
            self.func = function

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.func(x)
```

And the declaration could look a little something like this:

```
def calc1(x):
    return x+1
f = Objective(calc1)
f(1) --> f = 2
```

OR

```
f2 = Objective("x+1")
f2(1) --> f2 = 2
```

Now, as some of you might already noticed, the code won't work if the input is a string, because the definition of the function `func` only works within the `__init__` (*and* yes, I know, the implementation of `eval` is not 100% correct either, but for simplicity I wrote it like this). My question is, how do I declare the function `func` within the `if` statement of the `__init__` function? I hope I could explain my issue understandably.

Comment: *"the definition of the function func only works within the `__init__`"* That's not true at all. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: Oh, I may have forgotten to mention a detail. It is vital the be within the '__init__' as I only want to declare the class 'Objective' and then just call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you add any instance variable, `self.func = func`:

```
class Objective():
    def __init__(self, function):
        if isinstance(function, str):
            def func(x): # no need for self
               return eval(function, locals())
            self.func = func # here

        elif callable(function):
            self.func = function

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.func(x)
```

Note, you don't need `self` in your definition of `func`. Also note, you haven't used an anonymous function anywhere. You've used a normal function definition.

Finally, (even though you probably shouldn't be doing this), you need to get `x` into the namespaces available to `eval`, so, something to the effect of:

```
return eval(function, locals())
```

Comment: Actually I am using asteval instead of eval. However, as this needs another import and is not directly part of the question, I simplified it by using eval(). But still, thank you for the note!